# Cannot call class from within another class

Tags: class, constructor

I have two classes. Inside class B, I want to use the method written in the class A. And I dont know why I get error.

Class A look like this:

```
public class ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships {
    
    //This Class updates account owner according to Territory__c record owner
    //Fires whenever Account is updated and inserted. Used in before update and after update
    
    //Variable
    List<Account> accs;
    
    
    //Constructor
    public ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships(List<Account> accList) {
        
        //Trigger.new Account List
        accs = accList;   
        
        
    }
    
    //Method - Change Owner according to Zip Code
    public void changeAccOwner() {
        //Some code here
     }
}
```

In Class B's method I want to use the "changeAccOwner()" method
So here is what I have done:

```
public class TerritoryOwner {
    
    
    //Variable
    List<Territory__c> ters;
    
    //Constructor
    public TerritoryOwner(List<Territory__c> terList) {
       ters = terList;
    }

    //Method B
    public void reassignAccOwner() {
        
     //Some Code here

         List<Account> relatedAccs = [SELECT Id                                    
                                      FROM   Account
                                      WHERE  BillingPostalCode = :ownerChangedTerNames];
            
          if(!relatedAccs.isEmpty()){
             List<ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships> updateAccOwners = new List<ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships> (relatedAccs);
             updateAccOwners.changeAccOwner();
            }
```

In the last two line of code, I hit these error:

Invalid initializer type List found for List: expected an Integer or a List of type ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships

I don't understand why the class would expect a list of its class object instead of a List of Account as defined in the first class. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, juste change the line with :ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships updateAccOwners = new ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships(relatedAccs);
Why using a list of your class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally you are trying to call the `changeAccOwner` method on a List. Instead you need to call it on the `ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships` instance.

Change:

```
if(!relatedAccs.isEmpty()){
    List<ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships> updateAccOwners = new List<ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships>(relatedAccs);
    updateAccOwners.changeAccOwner();
}
```

To:

```
ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships owners = new ZipCodeUpdateOwnerships(relatedAccs);

owners.changeAccOwner();
```